# How to loop a sound without gaps in www site

Tags: javascript, flash, audio

I need this sound `http://www.sound-effect.com/sounds1/noise/Static_Stereo.wav` to play in background of my site all the time. Is it possible to do this without gaps?

**I understand that in most of the sites sound is annoying for users, but this site is exception. This sound is essential in this site.**

Comment: Can you play it continuously? Yes. Without annoying your users? No.

Comment: One more reason I am glad I have sound muted 99% of the time on my machines...

Comment: I hope this remains unanswered indefinitely.

Comment: This sound is essential in this site.

Comment: @Justin I know that music is typically annoying to most people (myself very much included) but this type of "Why do you want to do this" is not very SO-like and not conducive to a community environment.

Comment: Don't vote this question down just because you don't understand the end use case.  The question is certainly on topic and interesting, and what he can say is probably restricted by contractual obligations.

Answer (score 0):

```
soundLoop.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Import your sound uncompressed to minimize the risk of gaps between loops. And of course, make sure your audiofile is made for looping.